# How to improve SQL execution query plan for script below

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I have a slow SQL query which execution plan run mainly on "index scan". I had added index to it which have help improve it to be "index seek". But out of 2 of the index (ixDocQueue_For_C_DocQueueDocManager and ixDocQueueFiles_For_C_DocQueueDocManager), it still using "index scan" rather that "index seek". May I know how can I improve it?

This is the query

```
SELECT dbo.docqueue.description,
       dbo.docqueue.doccode,
       dbo.docqueue.doctype,
       dbo.docqueue.generated,
       CASE
         WHEN dbo.docqueue.doctype BETWEEN 50 AND 54 THEN 'Word'
         WHEN ( dbo.docqueue.doctype BETWEEN 60 AND 64 )
               OR dbo.docqueue.doctype = 2108 THEN 'Excel'
         WHEN dbo.docqueue.doctype = 55 THEN 'Xml'
         WHEN dbo.docqueue.doctype = 90 THEN 'PDF'
       END                           AS DocumentType,
       CASE dbo.docqueue.generated
         WHEN 0 THEN 'Pending'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Completed'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Error'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'In Progress'
       END                           AS Status,
       CASE
         WHEN dbo.docqueue.generated = 0
               OR dbo.docqueue.generated >= 2 THEN dbo.docqueue.keycode
         WHEN dbo.docqueue.generated = 1 THEN dbo.docqueuefiles.mfcode
       END                           AS KeyCode,
       dbo.docqueue.dateenter,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.dixdocnr,
       dbo.docqueue.ucode,
       dbo.docqueue.docnumber,
       dbo.docqueue.machinename,
       dbo.docqueue.repoption,
       dbo.docqueue.reporttags,
       dbo.docqueue.docsel,
       dbo.docqueue.docext,
       dbo.docindex.foldernr,
       dbo.docindex.dateindex,
       dbo.docindex.docnr,
       dbo.docindex.docdate,
       dbo.docindex.confrank,
       dbo.docindex.mfnumber,
       dbo.docindex.docstatus,
       dbo.docindex.docorigin,
       dbo.docindex.keywords,
       dbo.docindex.note,
       dbo.docindex.ucodeupdate,
       dbo.docindex.storestatus,
       dbo.docindex.procstatus,
       dbo.docindex.numfiles,
       dbo.vpuser.uname,
       dbo.reflabels.NAME,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.markdelete,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.docfilenr,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.dateentered AS DateUpdated,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.filename,
       dbo.docqueuefiles.docfileid,
       dbo.doccheckout.cuser,
       dbo.doccheckout.cpath,
       dbo.doccheckout.cdatetime,
       dbo.doccheckout.machinename   AS CMachineName
FROM   dbo.doccheckout
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.docqueuefiles
                     ON dbo.doccheckout.docfileid = dbo.docqueuefiles.docfileid
                        AND dbo.doccheckout.cstatus = 1
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.docqueue
                     ON dbo.docqueuefiles.docnumber = dbo.docqueue.docnumber
                        AND dbo.docqueuefiles.doctype = dbo.docqueue.doctype
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vpuser
                    ON dbo.docqueue.ucode = dbo.vpuser.ucode
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.docindex
                    ON dbo.docqueuefiles.dixdocnr = dbo.docindex.docnr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reflabels
                    ON dbo.reflabels.code = ( CASE
                                                WHEN dbo.docqueue.generated = 0
                                                      OR dbo.docqueue.generated
                                                         >= 2
                                              THEN
                                                dbo.docqueue.keycode
                                                WHEN dbo.docqueue.generated = 1
                                              THEN
                                                dbo.docqueuefiles.mfcode
                                              END )
```

This is the index that still run on index scan,

```
CREATE INDEX ixDocQueueFiles_For_C_DocQueueDocManager ON DocQueueFiles 
(
docfileid,
docnumber,
doctype,
dixdocnr,
mfcode
)
include
(
markdelete,
docfilenr,
dateentered,
filename
)


CREATE INDEX ixDocQueue_For_C_DocQueueDocManager ON DocQueue 
(

docnumber,
doctype,
ucode,
generated,
keycode
)
INCLUDE
(
description,
doccode,
dateenter,
machinename,
repoption,
reporttags,
docsel,
docext
)
```

This is the execution plan. (on test environment, the statistic may not be accurate)

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyXvD-GJ5

Comment: i'm always suspicious when i see a mix of left and right joins.....

Comment: I see the problem "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" was the cause of the index scan.